# Parse.FacebookUtils.link doesn't seems to link my Parse user to Facebook user

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, parse-platform

I am getting a Facebook login user from a plugin used on my cordova app, I get that successfully and a new record is just added fine into Parse User class after the login. Now I tried to fetch the user by the email (say abd@user.com) and when I find him, I want to link him to the Facebook user I just logged him in.

```
  Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(authData,
    {
    success: function(_user) {

    var query = new Parse.Query('User');
    query.equalTo('username',data.email);
    query.first({

        success: function(user){

            if (!Parse.FacebookUtils.isLinked(user)) {
                // It reaches here                                  
             Parse.FacebookUtils.link(_user, null, {
                    success: function(aUser) {
                      // But neither here
                      alert("User logged in with Facebook!");
                  },
                    error: function(aUser, error) {
                      // Nor here
                      alert("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
                }
            });
            }
            },
            error: function(error){

            }   
        });
    },

           error: function(error1, error2){
           alert("Unable to create/login to as Facebook user");
           alert("  ERROR1 = "+JSON.stringify(error1));
           alert("  ERROR2 = "+JSON.stringify(error2));
    }
});// finish login
```

I am not sure why the two handlers are not called on `Parse.FacebookUtils.link` although the `Parse.FacebookUtils.isLinked` condition is fullfilled and the user appears not to be linked already (see my code above).

Comment: Hi, I am facing same issue, parse is creating new user entry if the same email id present in parse. Have you resolved it?